# Serial communication logging with data transfer

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, serial-port, serial-communication

I am trying to develop a communication script for a device that is connected through serial port in python. I am sending and receiving data from/to the device using functions. Now what I would like to do is keep a full communication log. If I am sending and receiving data that I initiate this is trivial. However the device is capable to send data on its own in 'unexpected' times, for example the device sends a message when it is restarted. I struggle to come up with an idea how to log these unexpected events.

My code so far:

```
import logging

def create_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger('main_log')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s.%(msecs)02d\t%(message)s", datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
    fh = TimedRotatingFileHandler(f'logfile.log', when="midnight", interval=5)
    fh.suffix = "%Y%m%d"
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    strm = logging.StreamHandler()
    strm.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.addHandler(strm)
    return logger

LOGGER = create_logger()

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", timeout=1, baudrate=115200, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=False,
                             bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS)

def communication_function1():
    LOGGER.info("TO DEVICE: something...")
    port.write(b"somedata")
    reply = port.read()
    LOGGER.info(f"FROM DEVICE: received some data {reply}")
    return 'success'


def communication_function2():
    LOGGER.info("TO DEVICE: other thing...")
    port.write(b"otherdata")
    reply = port.read()
    LOGGER.info(f"FROM DEVICE: received some other data {reply}")
    return 'success'
```

The communication functions work perfectly and the data I send/receive are logged perfectly. However, in an event the device sends some unexpected data I am not able to receive or log it. My current idea is to set up a thread that constantly communicates, and kill that thread at the beginning of each communication function, and restart it at the end.

Idea for the threaded communication:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from threading import Event

def task(event):
    # execute a task in a loo#
    while (True):
        # Check if incoming bytes are waiting to be read from the serial input
        # buffer.
        if (ser.inWaiting > 0):
            # read the bytes and convert from binary array to ASCII
            data_str = port.read(port.inWaiting())
            LOGGER.into(data_str)

        time.sleep(0.01)
        if event.is_set():
            break

# create the event
event = Event()
# create and configure a new thread
thread = Thread(target=task, args=(event,))

def start_thread():
    thread.start()

def stop_thread():
    event.set()
    thread.join()
```

Maybe a decorator for each communication_function to stop and start the "background" communication thread.

However I feel like this is not the solution, and I am kind of stuck. What would be the proper way to implement something like this?

Comment: "*However the device is capable to send data on its own in 'unexpected' times*" --  If you know the maximum message size and rate, and the size of the system input buffer, you could estimate a maximum time that reading could be deferred. Otherwise for a device that can send unsolicited messages, you need to have a thread that is essentially always reading, i.e. waiting for input from this device. "*Maybe a decorator for each communication_function ...*" -- I have no idea what a "*decorator*" is.